# Text fragment creating using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text, split, fragment

I have a string like below -

```
var text="this is <b>a sample</b> long text. <i>Sample <b>tex</b>t <u>containing</u> some</i> bold underlined and it<i>alics wo</i>rds."
```

I want a JavaScript array like this

```
var textArr = [
  "this is ",
  "<b>a sample</b>",
  " long text. ",
  " ",
  "<i>Sample</i>",
  " ",
  "<i><b>tex</b></i>",
  "<i>t</i>",
  " ",
  "<i><u>containing</u></i>",
  " ",
  "<i>some</i>",
  " bold underlined and it",
  "<i>alics wo</i>",
  "rds" 
];
```

I need this because I need each fragment so that I can create that formatted canvas text object and place them on canvas.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: The second answer here seems pretty relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247838/best-way-to-parse-html-in-javascript
Also, please use modern HTML tags, `<strong>` and `<em>` instead of `<i>` and `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this piece of code:

```
var text="this is <b>a sample</b> long text. <i>Sample <b>tex</b>t <u>containing</u> some</i> bold underlined and it<i>alics wo</i>rds."

var t = document.createElement("div")
t.innerHTML = text;

var textArr = t.childNodes;
```