# How to add empty space between the elements when I use $('body').text()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

if I create for example a page with the following content:

```
<body>
<p>
ABC DEF<p>GHI</p>
JKL<br>MNO
</p>
</body>
```

Then I get in the browser:

```
ABC DEF

GHI

JKL
MNO
```

But when I now use `$('body').text()` then I get back:

```
ABC DEFGHI
JKLMNO
```

Is it possible to add an empty space between the elements? So that 'DEFGHI' and 'JKLMNO' are actually two words instead of one?

Here the link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7z3uqp0/3/) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `text()` and then replace `br` and `p` tags with spaces.

```
var text = $('body').html();
var str = text.replace( /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '\r\n'); // <br> to newline
var str2 = str.replace(/<\/?p[^>]*>/g, '\r\n'); // <p> to newline
var str3 = str2.replace(/  +/g, ' '); // multiple spaces to one

console.log(str3)
```

Resulting exactly the same structure as the HTML, but in text

```
ABC DEF

GHI

JKL
MNO
```

if you'll replace to empty space `' '` instead of `'\r\n'` you'll get:

```
ABC DEF GHI 
JKL MNO
```

- Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/n16dhaxc/) of the first one.
- Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/18pdm2Ln/6/) of the second one.

Comment: Thank you Alon for your answer. I also test .html() but for example '&' it returns '&amp;'. So for example 'A&B' is 'A&amp;B'. So I would need to replace all these signs. Or is there an easier way to keep '&'?

Comment: Basically it is not a good practice to [parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Your question includes a limited scenario as you asked about specific two tags. For this kind of task - small set of tags which needs to be replaced, [Regex replacement of the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/908624) can be just fine. If this is not the case, I would suggest parsing HTML with `DOMParser` and use selectors to get what you want, [Like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20767587/908624), for example.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you.